# How to create a List containing a sub dictionary keys , from nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Form nested dictionary, How to Create a List, containing Sub dictionary keys?

```
    dict_lbl = {
    "lbl1":{"name":"label1","item1":"Accounts",   "item2":"kannagu",    "shortcut":"F1","printitem":"You clicked label1"},
    "lbl2":{"name":"label2","item1":"Inventory",  "item2":"Saragu",     "shortcut":"F2","printitem":"You clicked label2"},
    "lbl3":{"name":"label3","item1":"Manufacture","item2":"Thayarippu", "shortcut":"F3","printitem":"You clicked label3"},
    "lbl4":{"name":"label4","item1":"PayRoll",    "item2":"Sambalam",   "shortcut":"F4","printitem":"You clicked label4"}
}
```

Need Result as follows:

```
['name', 'item1', 'item2', 'shortcut', 'printitem']
```

Comment: `list(dict_lbl['lbl1'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't assume nested dictionaries have the same keys yet you want to have a result including all unique keys, you can iterate through each nested dictionary and implement set union like this:

```
list(set().union(*[d.keys() for d in dict_lbl.values()]))

>>> ['item1', 'printitem', 'name', 'shortcut', 'item2']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keys`:

```py
output = list(dict_lbl['lbl1'].keys())
print(output) # ['name', 'item1', 'item2', 'shortcut', 'printitem']
```

(Actually you can omit `.keys()`!)